# @Transactional rollbackFor question

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

Supposing I mark a method `@Transactional(rollbackFor = PersistenceException.class)` in my Service layer and have a catch block as follows within the method.

```
try{
    serverStore.update(persistableObject);
     } catch (PersistenceException e) {

}
```

Will I ever even catch the PersistenceException?

I ask because the Persistence exception I'm guarding for is an intermittent deadlocking issue and I can't tell if I just haven't reproduced it since this change or it's not supposed to show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you flush the session (entity manager). By default, I think, it will get flush when the transaction is committed, so you won't be able to catch the exception in the method.